# How come I can not install plugins on my local Wordpress install?

Tags: 10.04, permissions, plugins, wordpress

I got **WordPress** up and running fine on **Ubuntu 10.04** by using [this source](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/installing-wordpress-3-0-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx.html/comment-page-3#comment-92106) except that when I try to update and install themes/plugins I get this following error message in wp-admin page:

> Installing Plugin: WordPress.com Stats
>   1.8.1 Downloading install package from http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/stats.1.8.1.zip…
>
> Unpacking the package…
>
> Could not create directory.
>   /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/upgrade/stats.tmp/stats
>
> Actions: Return to Plugin Installer

At first I thought I had to setup an FTP account but searched more and I found some information that says that I need to change the permissions of the wp-content folder which is located in the directory:

```
/var/www/wordpress/wp-content
```

I tried changing it by doing:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 wp-content/
```

but when I tried installing a plugin I got the same error message. I also tried passing it **755** as a permission but still got the same thing. I settled on **755** because it is more secure I have read.

**How can I solve this problem safely and securely?**

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the README file into the .zip file :

**== Installation ==**

The automatic plugin installer should work for most people. Manual installation is easy and takes fewer than five minutes.

1. Create a `stats` directory in your `plugins` directory. Typically that's `wp-content/plugins/stats/`.
2. Into this new directory upload the plugin files (`stats.php`, etc.)
3. Activate the plugin through the 'Plugins' menu in WordPress.
4. It will ask you to enter your WordPress.com API key. Don't use somebody else's key!
5. Sit back and wait a few minutes for your stats to come rolling in.

Comment: so you are basically saying that it is impossible to do automatic downloading of plugins, updates and themes?

Comment: @classer follow this step and you will install your plug-ins

Comment: what about updates of Wordpress?

Comment: @classer here -> https://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress and here -> https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-automatic-upgrade/.. if you want see screenshot here -> http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/wordpress_upgrade.htm